# Expose docker port to internal network only

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Running numerous dockers right now on a new build for a homelab server and trying to make sure everything is locked down and secure. I use the server for a variety of things, both requiring access from the outside world (nextcloud) and things that I will only access from my internal network (plex).  Of course the server is behind a router that limits open ports but looking for additional security - I would like to restrict those dockers that I want to only access via internal network, to 192.168.0.0/24. That way, if somehow a port became open on my router, it would not be exposed (am I being to paranoid?).

Currently docker-compose files are exposing ports via:

```
....

 ports:
   - 8989:8989
....
```

This is of course works fine but is accessible to the world should I open the port on my router.  I know i can bind to localhost  via

```
....
 ports:
   - 127.0.0.1:8989:8989
....
```

But that doesn't help me when I'm trying to access the docker from my internal network. I've read numerous articles regarding docker networks and various flags and also read about possibility iptables solution.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Simply do not declare any ports in docker-compose, they are automatically visible between containers.

I use an elasticsearch container in this way and a separate kibana can connect to it by the server name declated on the yml.

---

> if somehow a port became open on my router, it would not be exposed

Using this procedure the ports are never visible outside the docker environment (i.e. outside == in your local network).

If your concern is that ports are published in your LAN when doing the procedure I told you, they are not.

Comment: thanks - communication between containers is not the problem.  I need to access the web app running on my server when I'm on my laptop so some ports need to be exposed to the host.

Comment: Do you have to access microservices from outside your LAN ?

Comment: the question is about making the container available in their local network but not from outside their local network regardless of router settings

Comment: Sorry if I didn't seem to address the issue, but why not just publish the port to a specific LAN address instead ? Like `- 192.168.0.13:80:80`.  The router could have configured forwarded ports though.

Answer (score 2):

you are actually very close with

```
ports:
   - 127.0.0.1:8989:8989
```

as with this it is accessible locally on your server, fun enough, your bind to localhost trick is exactly what i was looking for my own  setup xD

from this point there are actually a couple of ways to set it up so that you can access it on your local network.

## SSH Tunneling

the first one is the one i'm using on my own setup: ssh forwarding

you can, if you haven't already, set up an .ssh/config file to forward localhost ports to your computer. taking your example into account the syntax is as follows

```
Host some-hostname
   HostName 192.168.x.x
   User user-of-server
   LocalForward 8989 127.0.0.1:8989
```

`some-hostname` is a shortname you can choose, `user-of-server` is the actual user you set up to log in with, `192.168.x.x` is the actual local ip address of your server and you can also include a `IdentityFile /path/to/ssh/key`. with this you can run `ssh some-hostname` to ssh into your server from any computer on your local network and your server will be available at `localhost:8989` on that specific computer

## Reverse Proxy

the second is a reverse proxy like nginx, this too can be run in a docker container and you could bind it to any port like say for example to 6443  and you can mount its config file into the container with

```
volumes:
 - 'config:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
ports:
 - 6443:443
volumes:
    config:
        driver: local
        driver_opts:
            type: none;
            o: bind
            device: "./config"
```

the in the ./config/defaul.conf you could set up something like

```
server { 
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   server_name 192.168.x.x;
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/signed_chain.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letencrypt/domain.key
   include /etc/nginx/includes/ssl.conf
   location /{
         ### force timeouts if one of backend is died ##
         ### such died, many backend, very timeouts ##
         proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

         ### Set headers ####
         proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding    "";
         proxy_set_header        Host               $host;
         proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host   $host:server_port;
         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;

         proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
         add_header              Front-End-Https    on;

         proxy_buffering off;

         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8989
   }
```

then it should be available on and only on 192.168.x.x:6443

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

```
docker-compose.yaml:
    ports:
      - "192.168.0.2:8089:8089"
```

In netstat I can see it is open on 192.168.0.2, so my local area network have connection to it.