# Cannot connect Lumen with PostgreSQL on Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, lumen

I have Lumen with PostgreSQL dockerized with docker-compose. Both works like a charm but I cannot make a migration or insert data because Lumen container is not connected to the PostgreSQL one, it appears the following error:

> SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused.Is
>   the server running on host "postgresql" (172.18.0.3) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 9906?

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7-apache

RUN apt-get upgrade -y \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install git-core libzip-dev openssl unzip zip libpq-dev postgresql-client -y \
    && apt-get clean \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo pdo_pgsql pgsql

# Apache Config
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

EXPOSE 8100
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: form_app
    depends_on:
    - postgresql
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html/
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  postgresql:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    container_name: form_pgsql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: formularios
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: formularios
      POSTGRES_DB: formularios
    ports:
      - "9906:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  admin:
    image: adminer
    container_name: form_adminer
    ports:
    - "8880:8080"
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Lumen
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=feZh5izBbOLIek27RQip9ciwTdRHPV7R
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost:8100
APP_TIMEZONE=UTC

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL=

DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=postgresql
DB_PORT=9906
DB_DATABASE=formularios
DB_USERNAME=formularios
DB_PASSWORD=formularios

CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
```

Comment: I think this should be ` "9906:9906"`, you are exposing port `9906` that visible to the outer world, not in container network. or you can specify DB port in connection to `5432`

Comment: Also see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56051409/expose-docker-port-to-internal-network-only ...